# Tiled gallery support in Wordpress 3.5.1

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I have a problem using the new Wordpress Gallery styles (e.g. `type="rectangular"`, `type=”square”`).

The `type` attribute is ignored and images are displayed in default type. See [here](http://www.czechschoolofcalifornia.com/?page_id=938).

My wordpress version is 3.5.1 and I am wondering if this version supports this feature. Because looking into Wordpress documentation on [Image > Gallery](http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/gallery/)  I can see that my Media Settings is missing the settings for `Image Gallery Carousal`.

Also, `Create Gallery` > `Gallery Setting` does not show the Type box where I could select `Default`| `Squares`|`Tyles` etc.

**Q1:** Does Wordpress version is 3.5.1 supports Tiled Galeries?

**Q2:** Is it possible that my Theme is inhibiting this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wordpress.com docs do not apply to the self-hosted WordPress solution (i.e. wordpress.org).

For self-hosted WordPress sites, the tiled galleries feature is available through the Jetpack plugin: http://jetpack.me/support/tiled-galleries/

Download jetpack: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that some features provided by wordpress.com do not apply to self-hosted Wordpress. Is is possible to upgrade my self-hosted webpage to get all the features?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a list of .com features w/ corresponding plugins, or a one-click solution. Jetpack will get you a lot of those features for sure. Also, check out the VIP list: http://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/

Comment: I already started integrating Jetpack, thanks! Really good plugin, something I was looking for. Will check out those VIPs as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install jetpack, there's this new solution http://wordpress.org/plugins/tiled-gallery-carousel-without-jetpack/